# Android app on top of libgdx game

Tags: android, libgdx

I'm trying to create an easy android quiz game that will be fetching questions/data from a server and will also include a login page. I was wondering whether I could build the app such that the login page and the signup pages are in the android folder and when the user has successfully signed in the game will now load...That way, I will have the app and the game in one

Comment: Couldn't the login page be part of the game and created with libgdx?

Comment: The login page can and probably should be created with libgdx. Any particular reason why you would want to seperate them?

Comment: Yes, I have the login page is supposed to save a token to a database and I am not sure how to do that with Libgdx, also Im using okhttp3 for networking and im not sure i do it with libgdx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AndroidLauncher in a default LibGDX project is an Activity. You can change your manifest to switch the `MAIN` and `LAUNCHER` intent filters from AndroidLauncher to your login Activity, and your login Activity can open the game with `startActivity()`.

Comment: I tried this earlier today and it was giving me drawable errors. Just tried now and it works great. Thanks..Turns out all it needed was a reboot